# How to replace NAs in a column with values of other columns based on different data frame in R?

Tags: r

So i have this datasets with 2 columns

df
| Zone Code | STREET |
| -------- | -------- |
| 1   | St. John St.   |
| 2   | NA   |
| 3   | NA   |

I want to replace NAs in df with a street name according to different data frame (street_df) that has complete list of the street name based on the Zone Code.

street_df
| Zone Code | STREET |
| -------- | -------- |
| 1   | St. John St.   |
| 2   | Roxbury St.   |
| 3   | MJ Ave.       |

I'm new with R and confused.

Comment: Welcome to SO. You maximize your chance of getting a useful answer if you provide a minimal reproducible example. [This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)  may help.

Answer (score 1):

One way is with `dplyr::rows_patch()`:

```
library(dplyr)
rows_patch(df, street_df, by="Zone Code")
```

Input

```
df<-tibble(`Zone Code`=c(1,2,3),`STREET`=c("St. John St.", NA, NA))
street_df<-tibble(`Zone Code`=c(1,2,3),`STREET`=c("St. John St","Roxbury St.","MJ Ave."))
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 3 × 2
  `Zone Code` STREET      
        <dbl> <chr>       
1           1 St. John St.
2           2 Roxbury St. 
3           3 MJ Ave.
```